Is this capacitor useable?
I am resurrecting an old tube radio. Most of the electrolytic caps measured near zero, and have been replaced.  This can has three capacitors in it.  They all measure near their nominal value.  Would it be safe to reuse these, or are there considerations beyond the basic value?  (I don't have any way to measure anything other than the capacitance.)
Motorola Type FP capacitor


Has it been idle a very long time? Those three-in-one might benefit from re-forming while removed from circuit, with a very low-current variable DC supply...you can get a sense of leakage current at the same time. I'd imagine a replacement is either expensive or unobtanium. Nevertheless, they do tend to go dry with time, and are not immortal. Looks like one twist-tab GND has broken off - flex these with care. If you do try to re-form, be sure to discharge before re-testing with C-meter!

Need a better scan of that schematic

It may be okay to let them inside. But consider this:
You are on a rescue mission and the device is open and the solder iron is hot. But maybe you don‘t need to replace some of the caps, they are still holding enough capacity and looking fine. You put the radio together and enjoy the nice sound and are quite pleased with your work. Fast forward a few weeks, the radio doesn‘t turn on anymore and you need to open it up again. The caps, which you didn‘t replace, are blown and you need to wait to replace them. I have been in this situation before and my advice is to replace all parts which may fail soon, if you can afford it.
But experiences are like apple pie, make them yourself.
